# XSLT: Need to convert name value pair content into XML

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm new to XSLT. I have a requirement to convert an XML containing name value pair into target XML. 
I need to generate a target XML where each FieldName is an element name and it value is FieldValue. Please find below the output which I need.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Source XML:

```html
<SC>
 <Header>
  <Record>
   <FieldName>Schema</FieldName>
   <FieldValue>OrderHeader</FieldValue>
  </Record>
  <Record>
   <FieldName>Order</FieldName>
   <FieldValue>1234</FieldValue>
  </Record>
 </Header>
 <Detail>
  <Record>
   <FieldName>Schema</FieldName>
   <FieldValue>OrderItem</FieldValue>
  </Record>
  <Record>
   <FieldName>Item</FieldName>
   <FieldValue>1</FieldValue>
  </Record>
  <Record>
   <FieldName>Qty</FieldName>
   <FieldValue>10</FieldValue>
  </Record>
 </Detail>
 <Detail>
  <Record>
   <FieldName>Schema</FieldName>
   <FieldValue>OrderItem</FieldValue>
  </Record>
  <Record>
   <FieldName>Item</FieldName>
   <FieldValue>2</FieldValue>
  </Record>
  <Record>
   <FieldName>Qty</FieldName>
   <FieldValue>20</FieldValue>
  </Record>
 </Detail>
</SC>
```

Target XML to be generated:

```html
<SC>
    <OrderHeader>
        <Order>1234</Order>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderItem>
        <Item>1</Item>
        <Qty>10</Qty>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
        <Item>2</Item>
        <Qty>20</Qty>
    </OrderItem>
</SC>
```

XSLT which I tried: I'm not getting the desired output

```
<xsl:template match="Header">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Record"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:if test="FieldName = 'Structure'">
        <xsl:element name="{FieldValue}">
            <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:element name="{FieldName}">
        <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another option that is similar to Martin's.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Header|Detail">
    <xsl:element name="{Record[1]/FieldValue}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Record[position()>1]"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:element name="{FieldName}">
      <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to process the first `Record` child as a container element and the following siblings are to be transformed as in your description:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="SC">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Record[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SC/*/Record[1]">
        <xsl:element name="{FieldValue}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Record"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SC/*/Record[position() gt 1]">
        <xsl:element name="{FieldName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```